# Foreign key aren't sharing values with parent table

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I made a sharing table for two entities. I made both their primary keys as foreign keys into that intersecting table. Then, I insert some values into parent tables. Now I check that intersect tables but its empty have not a single value in it while parent tables have. What am I supposed to do?  (College Project)

Here's the code for intersection table:

```
create table Pro_emp (
    pid int foreign key references project(pid),
    eid int foreign key references employee(eid),
    date date default getdate(),
);
```

Comment: Foreign keys are usually used in the `ON` clauses of `JOIN` operations.

Comment: You're Right. will it work if i compare table using these clauses. while console is not showing a thing in 'em??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A foreign key is not automatically inserted into `Pro_emp`.
But every new inserted value for `pid` and `eid` has to be within their referenced parent table.
So, insert a new record into `Pro_emp` having valid `pid` and `eid` values.

Comment: It means i should insert values into intersect table. Then Join them in a query if somewhere they got matched then I'll get the result?

Comment: yes, exactly:
after insertion, do something like

"select * from Pro_emp i
left join project p on i.pid = p.pid
left join employee e on i.eid = e.eid".

Comment: for testing, you may want to start with "insert into Pro_emp (pid,eid) values (1,1);" if there is a pid=1 resp eid=1 in projects resp. employee

Comment: so if this solves your issue, please *accept* the answer!